# android UnsupportedOperationException in ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android, exception

I am trying to create an onDisimiss listener to my app as for now this is what i have

The activity

```
public class listview_test extends Activity {
ListView list;
String[] web = {
        "Google Plus",
        "Twitter",
        "Windows",
} ;
Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.icon,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_test);
    final CustomList adapter = new
            CustomList(listview_test.this, web, imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(listview_test.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    list,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
            );
    list.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    list.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
}
}
```

And the custom adapter

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context,
                  String[] web, Integer[] imageId) {
    super(context, R.layout.weather_item, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_item, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
    txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    return rowView;
}
```

For some reason every time i am swiping an item to dismiss it force closes and gives me this exception

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

In this line

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

is thrown when you back an `Adapter` by an array or non-modifiable `List`. Since you cannot change their size, deleting is impossible.

Instead, modify your Adapter so it accepts a `List` **instead of** an array and make sure that the `List` you pass off is fully flexible.

Something like

```
List <String> web = new ArrayList <String> ();
web.add ("Google Plus");
web.add ("Twitter");
//etc.
```

is enough to ensure a flexible list.

This means that your `CustomList` adapter should also call up to the superclass constructor that also accepts in a `List`, which in this case is

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

For more information refer to the [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) documentation.

Comment: so instead of an "ArrayAdapter" i should use ListAdapter?

Comment: @user3068269 no, `ListAdapter` is an interface implemented by `ArrayAdapter`. Continue to use `ArrayAdapter` but change the `super` call.